# How can I disable links in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, email

How can I disable clickable links in Thunderbird emails, that is, I want to copy/past every link if I need, but disable click-opening. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to the AU community!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this](https://blindbites.wordpress.com/2013/11/08/how-to-disable-links-in-thunderbird) site, I was able to find out a workaround to disable the link-clicking ability.

0. Open Thunderbird
1. Go to Edit>Preferences.
2. Go to the Advanced>General tab, then click Config Editor.
3. Promise that you will be careful
4. Type this into the search bar: `network.protocol-handler.external-default`
5. Double click on the option that appears to make it `false`.
   Note: If it's alerady `false`, you are not able to click on any link anyway.
6. Done, you can now close the two windows. Close Thunderbird if you don't need it open at the moment.

---

Hint: if you set this option but occasionally need to open a link, you can drag & drop it into a web browser.